# How come any selection i make on this <select> tag drop down menu always defaults to the last if statement i have set it?

Tags: javascript, html

Im pretty new to developing webpages, so if the answer is stupidly obvious then I apologise. I am trying to create a fully functioning playback rate change menu on my video player, but every time i select any option on the dropdown menu, the result i get from my .js always defaults to the last if statement. in this case, selecting for example "0.5x" speed, it will always default to 1.75, since thats the last thing i mentioned in my js if statements.

```
var playbackSpeeds = document.getElementById ("speedValues");
speedValues.addEventListener ("input", changePlaybackSpeed)
function changePlaybackSpeed()
{
    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "2x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 2.0;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "0.5x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 0.5;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "0.75x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 0.75;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "1x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 1.0;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "1.25x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 1.25;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "1.5x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 1.5;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value = "1.75x")
    {
        myVideo.playbackRate = 1.75;
    }
}`
```

Id like for the end result to actually work use the speed that the user will set it, rather than what is happening now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The comparison operator is `==`, not `=` which is the assignment operator.

Comment: :) use `==` instead `=`, using `=` (assignment operator) you are actually assigning a value so `if statement` is getting true till end.

Answer (score 1):

you should give `===`

```
var playbackSpeeds = document.getElementById ("speedValues");
speedValues.addEventListener ("input", changePlaybackSpeed)
function changePlaybackSpeed(){
if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "2x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 2.0;
}

if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "0.5x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 0.5;
}

if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "0.75x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 0.75;
}

if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "1x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 1.0;
}

if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "1.25x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 1.25;
}

if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "1.5x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 1.5;
}

if (document.getElementById("speedValues").value === "1.75x")
{
    myVideo.playbackRate = 1.75;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single equals `=` and you need a double `==` or triple `===` equals.

When you write something like this in JavaScript...

```
var x = 5;
if(x = 3){
   alert("it's three")
}
```

...you are setting `x` to 5, then setting it again to 3.

Instead you need this:

```
var x = 5;
if(x === 3){
   alert("it's three")
}
```

That will check if `x` has the value of `3`. It is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) to use the `===` instead of `==` because `===` is type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to refer to the option id.

```
<option id='1'></option>
```

javascript:

```
if(document.getElementbyId("1").value='1.5'){
 myVideo.playbackRate = 1.5;
}
```